# New to ERD's and Database mgmt

Tags: sql, database, erd

I have an assignment due in my intro database class - and I'm stumped by one thing.  We have been given 5 tables to create for a hotel - Bookings, Clients, OtherCharges, Payments, and Rooms.  Within the Clients table, we have the following attributes - ClientID(PK), FirstName (required), LastName(required), Birthdate, Street, City, Province, PostalCode, Phone (Either phone or email is required), Email (either phone or email is required), CreditCard(must contain no duplicates).  I have constructed my ERD in Visio (as instructed), and have done all of my TABLE CREATE's in my SQL worksheet.  My question is twofold:
A)  How do I represent the email/phone requirement in Visio?  There is a checkbox for required attributes, but I can't check them both, as they are not both required.  What gives?
B)  How do I handle that in my SQL?  Is it a CHECK constraint?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the standard Visio "Database Model Diagram" you cannot directly represent multi-column check constaints. And for the second question, yes it is a CHECK constraint.

Comment: How would you word that constraint?  Would it be CHECK email = NOT NULL or phone= NOT NULL?

Comment: The exact systax may be database dependent, on SQL Server, it would be CHECK (email IS NOT NULL OR phone IS NOT NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Just stick with varchar for phone and email at the database level. If you want to enforce more sophisticated validation, it is better to implement that at the application level.

Comment: Sorry to seem simple, but what would the data type (CHAR, VARCHAR, etc.) have to do with enforcing a restriction?  I think the instructor wants some sort of distinction made regarding one or the other (email or phone) being a required field (NOT NULL).